# How do I change a single char to an int in sml/nj

Tags: smlnj

I am just trying to change the char to int and return the int.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `Char.ord` ([Basis library page](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/char.html#SIG%3aCHAR.ord%3aVAL)).

e.g., `Char.ord #"a"`